# How to access redux store in Cypress if the application is running outside of Cypress tests

Tags: redux, cypress

In my E2E Cypress tests, I would like to access the Redux store of the application under test and dispatch some actions to change some of the redux store value. I've read some blogs and tutorials about accessing Redux store from Cypress (https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/11/14/testing-redux-store/) that I need to expose the application store in the **src/index.js** which should sits inside the application package.

For your information, our "application under test" and Cypress tests sit in different project structure (different package names).

```
const store = createStore(reducer)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

// expose store when run in Cypress
if (window.Cypress) {
  window.store = store
}
```

Is it possible for Cypress to access the redux store of the application which runs in a different package?

Comment: It should be possible, since you are just adding store to the app window. Why not try it and see?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `cy.window` to first access to window and then dispatch an acition like this:

```
cy.window().then(win => {
  if (win.store) {
    win.store.dispatch(...));
  }
})
```

and make sure before this use `cy.visit()` without this there is no window object to get.